# How do I programmatically download a file behind Oracle's OTN login page?

Tags: oracle, powershell, webclient, wget, chocolatey

I'm trying to create a [Chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org) package for the [Oracle WebLogic Server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/index.html) binaries. I know that I must pass a special cookie for the "license acceptance". But, I'm getting stuck trying to get past the login form. I've been researching how to get it done with `wget` or `curl` and I'm trying to map that to `System.Net.WebClient`, where applicable.

I have the following so far, which works for other Oracle downloads with license acceptance (like the JDK).

```
$url  = "http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/middleware/12c/wls/1212/wls1212_dev.zip"
$temp = Join-Path $ENV:TEMP "oracle-weblogic-server.zip" 

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $true }
$client.Headers.Add("Cookie", "gpw_e24=http://www.oracle.com")
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile($url, $temp)
```

I've read in [a few places](http://www.pythian.com/blog/how-to-download-oracle-software-using-wget-or-curl/) that the Oracle download page supports "basic" authentication. Which should mean setting a `NetworkCredential`. So, I set this before downloading...

```
$client.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
```

But, the response seems to contain a login page! (here is a fragment of the form). **UPDATE:** I think only the Oracle support portal supports basic authentication :(

```
<form action="https://login.oracle.com/mysso/signon.jsp" method="post" name="myForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="v" value="v1.4">
  <input type="hidden" name="p_submit_url" value="https://login.oracle.com:443/sso/auth">
  <input type="hidden" name="p_cancel_url" value="https://edelivery.oracle.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="p_error_code" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="ssousername" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="subscribername" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="authn_try_count" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="contextType" value="external">
  <input type="hidden" name="username" value="string">
  <input type="hidden" name="contextValue" value="/oam">
  <input type="hidden" name="password" value="sercure_string">
  <input type="hidden" name="challenge_url" value="https://login.oracle.com/mysso/signon.jsp">
  <input type="hidden" name="request_id" value="903089276773533395">
</form>
```

I also tried [writing the authorization header directly](http://www.hashemian.com/blog/2007/06/http-authorization-and-net-webrequest-webclient-classes.htm), but I got the same result.

```
  $client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("${username}:${password}")))
```

I stumbled on an old message about [OTN **not allowing** command-line authentication](https://community.oracle.com/message/9885417#9885417). I don't know how to verify that, but other sites are saying [the same thing](http://only4left.jpiwowar.com/2010/04/wget_otn_downloads/) (they might be parroting one source, though). But, I swear I've seen people `POST`ing credentials with `wget` and `--post-data`, I can't find it now.

I played with the `WebClient.UploadValues` to no avail. Maybe I'm picking the wrong names or the wrong URL? I have noticed some redirects in the responses and when I'm manually watching the traffic (Inspect Element | Network in Chrome). But, I don't know what do with this information!

```
$login = "https://login.oracle.com/mysso/signon.jsp"

$data = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
$data.Add("username", "username")
$data.Add("password", "password")

$client.UploadValues($login, "POST", $data)
```

So, first, and most importantly, is there any way to login to OTN from the command line. Second, how do I do it with `WebClient`?

Comment: Here's a 2011 "bug" and workaround directly from Oracle that seems to be using one `wget` to authenticate and save the cookies and a second to download the file, but I can't be entirely sure: https://blogs.oracle.com/supportportal/entry/use_of_wget_instead_of_downloa

Comment: Basic authentication should include the username and password in the URL, right?

Comment: I think I had it wrong, at least, the article I linked to says the basic auth works only with the Oracle support page. Not the OTN.

Comment: I don't know if this will take you any further. https://github.com/ardentperf/racattack/blob/master/makeDVD/auto.sh

Answer (score 1):

This method could possibly get you into trouble as it seems like the required login is there to specifically ensure it's a human on the other end.

Comment: Yeah, but programmers are *really* stubborn ;)